# Refreshing Kivy Image with Python

Tags: python, image, kivy

I have a weather app I've written in Python/Kivy, it successfully downloads and loads the image at application start but the weather map changes daily and its not refreshing. The Kivy documentation discusses `nocache: True`,  `image.reload()` & I've tried `self.the_24h_chart.source.reload()` and both error.

How can I reload an image file? Pseudo code:

1. download new image and overwrite original with same name
2. reload the image

My current Kivy code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python 
# -*- decoding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.loader import Loader
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import socket
import urllib




#--------------- kivy code ------------------
Builder.load_string('''

<Chart1>:
    name: 'chart1'
    the_24h_chart: _chart_img

    Image:
        source: 'images/chart.jpg'
        nocache: True
        id: _chart_img
        size_hint_y: None
        height: dp(420)
 ''')
#-------------------------------------------


class Chart1(Screen):

    def update_chart1(self, sec):
      try:
        urllib.urlretrieve('http://wxcharts.eu/charts/gfs/uk/06/overview_030.jpg', 'images/chart.jpg')
        self.the_24h_chart.source = 'images/chart.jpg'
        self.Image.reload()
      except:
        print 'Error Updating Image'
        pass


class ScreenManagerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        self.chart1_screen = Chart1(name = 'chart1')
        sm.add_widget(self.chart1_screen)
        return sm


    def on_start(self):
        event1 = Clock.create_trigger(self.chart1_screen.update_chart1)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.chart1_screen.update_chart1, 3600) # 1 Hour
        event1()

#===========================================================
# run the App !
ScreenManagerApp().run()
```

Comment: As described, this sounds like a bug in `Image.reload`. Are you able to provide a minimal runnable example to test?

Comment: I've edited the original post, now working example with the reload image error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Chart1 has no attribute named Image, so `self.Image.reload()` raises an error. You would see this in the traceback, but you've added a catchall try/except that completely hides what's going on. For this reason, using a catchall try/except is almost never a good idea - if you expect something to go wrong, catch only the specific exception that will be raised, and also try to make sure that the same exception can't be raised in any other way.

The simplest way to access your Image instance is instead to use `self.ids._chart_img.reload()`.